# How can you shorten a function with a condition

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter

I have a function like this which is supposed to filter a nested array inside an object. I do not understand how you can shorten the code so that nothing breaks.

```
const getCommonCreditProps = (creditProgram, term) => {
  let currentInsurances;
  term > 47 ? currentInsurances = creditProgram.insuranceProducts.filter((i) => i.code !== 'ins_cp_st_avtomoblst_4').map((i) => {
  let rateDiscount = 0;
    try {
      rateDiscount = i.discountFieldName + 1;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

  return {
    ...i,
    productName: getInsurancesName(i.type, rateDiscount || 0),
    discount: rateDiscount || 0,
  };
}) : currentInsurances = creditProgram.insuranceProducts.filter((i) => i.code !== 'ins_cp_st_avtomoblst_4').map((i) => {
  let rateDiscount = 0;
    try {
      rateDiscount = i.discountFieldName - 1;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

  return {
    ...i,
    productName: getInsurancesName(i.type, rateDiscount || 0),
    discount: rateDiscount || 0,
  };
})

return { currentInsurances };
};
```

How to reduce functions and avoid code duplication?

Comment: Start with removing the ternary operator. It makes the code unreadable and you're using it wrong.

Comment: It's a bit strange that your code says `i.discountFieldName`. Did you mean `i[discountFieldName]`?

Comment: The try catches can be removed pretty easily. Extracting the common part to a separate function called conditionally will make it really succinct while maintaining readability

Answer (score -1):

You can use destructuring, and an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to reduce duplicated code and compact it down. You don't need the try/catch, because you can instead check if discountFieldName is undefined.

Also, true/false coerces to 1/0 when added. Therefore, `t>47 || -1` is equivalent to `t > 47 ? 1 : -1`.

```js
const getCommonCreditProps = (creditProgram, term:t) => ({
  currentInsurances: creditProgram
    .insuranceProducts.filter(i => i.code !== 'ins_cp_st_avtomoblst_4')
    .map((i,dfn) => (discount=>({
        ...i,
        productName: getInsurancesName(i.type, discount),
        discount
      }))((dfn=i.discountFieldName)===undefined ? 0 : dfn + (t>47 || -1))
    )
})
```

Comment: This code is way too clever. The IIFE is really bad for readability and two ternarys on the same line are equally bad

Comment: @AdamJenkins There are no longer two ternary operators on the same line. I bet you love it even more now :)